# How to hide the cursor in the terminal using OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to build a terminal-based text editor. Right now, whenever I print out text into the terminal, there is a bit of a flicker that I assume has to do with the cursor moving around.

As such, I want to try hiding the cursor before each printing session and unhide it after printing is finished. However, I am not sure how I can do this using OCaml.

I have tried using Lambda-term. but for some reason that was not working. Also I don't know how I feel about using lambda-term just for hiding the cursor.

Comment: What makes you think there's a cursor flying around? Unless you're using a telex terminal form the 1980s, I very much doubt there is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `civis`/`cnorm` control sequencies to hide/unhide cursor if your terminal supports it:

```
(* hide the cursor *)
printf "\027[?25l%!";
sleep 2;
(* restore the cursor *)
printf "\027[?25h%!"
```

Comment: what is the purpose of sleep 2?

Comment: @Shiv: purely demonstrative (to hide & unhide the cursor in one shot).